# How to execute multple commands in one shot

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below two commands to accomplish a task in a unix terminal:

```
% cat do_vtran*.cmd | grep vtran | tac | awk 'NR==1 {FILE=$0; next} 1; END{print FILE}' | tac > FILE "
% source FILE "
```

Output of FILE (after first command) contains the below 7 lines:

```
line1: echo step 1 start
line2: bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_sanity_dft.vtran"
line3: echo step 2 start 
line4: bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_off.vtran" 
line5: echo step 3 start
line6: bsub -I -q vtran "vtran -scan_pad 0X ../test/pm30_60_224_jtag_bist_full_vector_on.vtran" 
line7: echo end all steps
```

Qn is that How can club the above two commands to one which execute (at one shot) all 7 lines one by one in command promt.

I have already tried

```
% cat do_vtran*.cmd | grep vtran | tac | awk 'NR==1 {FILE=$0; next} 1; END{print FILE}' | tac | bash
```

which executes only line1 & line2; stops thereafter.

Comment: What if you manually execute one command after the other?

Comment: I need to use it in a perl script.. there i cant execute manually one by one..